# Is my explanation about big o correct in this case?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to explain to my friend why *7n - 2 = O(N)*. I want to do so based on the definition of big O.

Based on the definition of big O, **f(n) = O(g(n))** if:

We can find a real value **C** and integer value *n0 >= 1* such that:

- *f(n)<= **C** . g(n)* for all values of *n >= n0*.

In this case, is the following explanation correct?

- *7n - 2 <= **C** . n*
- *-2 <= **C** . n - 7n*
- *-2 <= n (**C** - 7)*
- *-2 / (**C** - 7) <= n*

if we consider ***C*** = 7, mathematically, *-2 / (**C** - 7)* is equal to negative infinity, so

- *n >= (negative infinity)*

It means that for all values of *n >= (negative infinity)* the following holds:

- *7n - 2 <= 7n*

Now we have to pick *n0* such that for all *n >= n0* and *n0 >= 1* the following holds:

- *7n - 2 <= 7n*

Since for all values of *n >= (negative infinity)* the inequality holds, we can simply take *n0 = 1*.

Comment: Dividing by zero like that is kind of icky, why don't you just plug c=7 into the original formula and derive an n0 from that? Also writing 7n - 2 = O(N) is common, but really an abuse of notation. A function cannot equal a set of functions.

Comment: what happens if you try with 7n + 2?

Comment: @mrmcgreg, then 2/(c-7) <= n, so we can consider c = 8 and n0 = 2. I know that we can do it simple like harlod mentioned, but I'm sticking to an example from an algorithm book which simply said c = 7 and n0 = 1, now I want to see is my explanation correct? I want to certainly use math for that.

Comment: you're right, since you get to choose the constant that still works. This is really more of a mathematical question. I'm not sure if you can say that 1 / 0 = Infinity. Even in the extended real system this isn't true.

Comment: Have a look at your first line: `7n - 2  ≤ cn` holds if `c = 7` and `n ≥ 1` due to `7n - 2 ≤ 7n` holds for all integers. Note that division by zero does not results in infinity. It is just not defined. If someone "divides" `x` by zero, he means `lim_{h → 0} x/h`.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track here. Fundamentally, though, the logic you're using doesn't work. If you are trying to prove that there exist an n<sub>0</sub> and c such that f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, then you can't start off by assuming that f(n) ≤ cg(n) because that's ultimately what you're trying to prove!

Instead, see if you can start with the initial expression (7n - 2) and massage it into something upper-bounded by cn. Here's one way to do this: since 7n - 2 ≤ 7n, we can (by inspection) just pick n<sub>0</sub> = 0 and c = 7 to see that 7n - 2 ≤ cn for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>.

For a more interesting case, let's try this with 7n + 2:

> 7n + 2
>
> ≤ 7n + 2n (for all n ≥ 1)
>
> = 9n

So by inspection we can pick c = 9 and n<sub>0</sub> = 1 and we have that 7n + 2 ≤ cn for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, so 7n + 2 = O(n).

Notice that at no point in this math did we assume the ultimate inequality, which means we never had to risk a divide-by-zero error.